# How do I access the super class of TreeSelectionListener in Java?

Tags: java, anonymous-objects

```
this.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {

            // How do I access the parent tree from here?           
        }           
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by parent tree?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. New to java and didn't realise TreeSelection was an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeSelectionListener` is an interface, so the only parent class would be `Object`, which you should be able to call with `super`.

If you meant calling some method of the enclosing class, you can call it directly as within a method.

Comment: Seems Like I was the one who downvoted the answer, because I did not get enough info to the posted Question: "How do I access the parent Object of an anonymous object in Java?". I did not understand why can I use super in the anonymous class... I thought you can't, because any call to `super` or `this` will correspond to the outer class, not the parent of anonymous... 
Hm... Sorry... I still don't know the correct answer, but seems like I was in a rush... Better would be to find the actual correct answer and then take a decision...

Answer (score 36):

You can use `OuterClass.this`:

```
public class Test {

    String name; // Would normally be private of course!

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.name = "Jon";
        t.foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test t = Test.this;
                System.out.println(t.name);
            }
        };
        r.run();
    }
}
```

However, if you just need to access a *member* in the enclosing instance, rather than getting a reference to the instance itself, you can just access it directly:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name); // Access Test.this.name
    }
};
```

Comment: @Chris: In what way does it not answer the question? It absolutely shows how to get at the enclosing instance. At least, it answers the question I believe was asked. It's far from a clear question (the term "parent Object" isn't defined) but I assumed the OP meant "enclosing instance", in which case it answers the question.

Comment: Although Java itself doesn't define "parent", it's a common term for superclasses in object-oriented programming languages. A web search for "Java parent" or "Object-oriented parent" will show millions of hits. For a quick reference look at wikipedia for "class diagram", it says: "The superclass(base class) in the generalization relationship is also known as the "parent", superclass, base class, or base type."

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but that's ignoring the context of an anonymous type, from the class... and the comment in the method, which talks about a *tree*, clearly distinct from the *listener*. I stand by my interpretation of the ambiguous question as being a valid interpretation.

Comment: I upvoted this because it answered my question which was how to access the outer class from within the inner class and I was directed to this page by Google. I accept what Chris is saying but I think that's a point of semantics. The fact is that this was useful to me, even if it technically didn't answer the asked question.